# Table vertical centering : what am I doing wrong?

Tags: tables

I know there are multiple questions and their answers on the topic but I can't make it work. I tried multiple codes to make a table, the one I have now works as long as I don't use images. And I would like very much to use them.

here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,esvect}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]},
  stretch = 0,
  rowsep = 6pt,
  hlines = {1.2pt},
  vlines = {1.2pt},
}

        Famille
    & 
        Nom
    & 
        Schéma 
    &
        Torseur Cinématique
 \\   
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Liaison à direction
     &
     Glissière
     & 
     \includegraphics[height=2cm]{glissiere.png}
     & 
        $VVV = \displaystyle \frac{zz}{\displaystyle \int dx}$
\\  
        
     &
        Plane
     & 
          \includegraphics[height=2cm]{plane.png}
     &
         $VVV = \displaystyle \frac{zz}{\displaystyle \int dx}$
\\   
\end{tblr}


\end{document}
```

Here is the result, despite `Q[c,m]` :
[image: TableOfMWE]

You can see that the content of the second and fourth column are lower than expected and in the third column it's higher : as if the bottom of the images were vertically aligned with the text in the other columns

If you like overleaf here is a link to a directory of my MWE :
https://www.overleaf.com/read/wmbbxqyssxvd

I know that using images complicates my MWE but it is at the heart of my problem. so here they are :
[image: LiaisonGlisiere]
[image: LiaisonPlane]

Follow up question : Why are the tables in LaTeX so awful to use ?

Comment: "as if the bottom of the images were vertically aligned with the text in the other column" not "as if" that is exactly what you have specfied, each table cell is placed with its reference point on the baseline and by default the reference point of an image is on it bottom edge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move images baseline to images vertical center. This can be done on several vays, but seems (to my opinion) that `valign` of `adjustbox` is the most  handy. Doing this you not need option `m` in columns specifications:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}   % <---
\usepackage{tikz,esvect}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\newcommand\ds{\displaystyle}    % <---


\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[c] Q[c]Q[c] Q[c, mode=dmath]}, % <---
                 colsep  = 2pt,
                 row{1}  = {mode=text},                      % <---
                 hlines  = {1.2pt},  vlines = {1.2pt},
                }
Famille & Nom       & Schéma    & Torseur Cinématique               \\
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Liaison à direction
        & Glissière & \includegraphics[height=2cm, valign=m]{example-image-duck}%{glissiere.png}
                                & VVV = \frac{zz}{\ds \int dx}      \\
        & Plane     & \includegraphics[height=2cm, valign=m]{example-image-duck}%{plane.png}
                                & VVV = \frac{zz}{\ds \int dx}
                \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Off-topic: In above MWE are

- for shorter code for `\displaystyle` is defined new command `\ds`
- last column in is display math style (do you really need integral in fraction as display style?)
- used is only `tabularray` syntax (`\colsep` in table preamble instead `\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}` before table)

[image]

- In cases, when for images you insert `tikz` code, than for moving image baseline to it vertical center, add  `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` to `tikzpicture` options.

**Edit:**

In case, that texts in some cells have few lines, that for their vertical centering you should replace `X[c]` with X[c, ]`:

```
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[c,m] Q[c,m]Q[c] Q[c, mode=dmath]}, % <---
                 colsep  = 2pt,
                 row{1}  = {mode=text},                      % <---
                 hlines  = {1.2pt},  vlines = {1.2pt},
                }
Famille & Nom       & Schéma    & Torseur Cinématique               \\
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Liaison à direction
        & Glissière & \includegraphics[height=2cm, valign=m]{example-image-duck}%{glissiere.png}
                                & VVV = \frac{zz}{\ds \int dx}      \\
        & {Plane\\ Plane\\ Plane}    
                    & \includegraphics[height=2cm, valign=m]{example-image-duck}%{plane.png}
                                & VVV = \frac{zz}{\ds \int dx}
                \\
    \end{tblr}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have marked it as accepted but could you help me further : I want to use several lines like so : { Plane \\ Plane \\ Plane } in a cell and it's not centered anymore

Comment: @LMT-PhD, re< to add `m` to column specifier options:  `X[c,m]`. I will return to your question ASAP.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that:

- for the vertical alignment of the images, we need `h` and not `m`;
- the text of column 2 is aligned vertically with the `=` of column 4, if
  you want to align vertically with the image, I haven't found anything
  other than a manual adjustment with `{\\[-1ex]Plane}` or use `adjustbox`

**the code**

```
    \documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680131/table-vertical-centering-what-am-i-doing-wrong
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}% <-- added
    \begin{document}
    \setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
    \begin{tblr}{
    %colspec = {Q[c]Q[c]Q[c,h]Q[c]},
    colspec = {*{4}{Q[c]}},% with adjsutbox
    stretch = 0,
    rowsep = 6pt,
    hlines = {1.2pt},
    vlines = {1.2pt},
    }
            Famille
        & 
            Nom
        & 
            Schéma 
        &
            Torseur Cinématique
    \\   
        \SetCell[r=2]{} Liaison à direction
        &
        Glissière
        & 
        %\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
        \adjustbox{valign=M}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        & 
                $VVV = \displaystyle \frac{zz}{\displaystyle \int dx}$
    \\        
        &
        %{\\[-1ex]Plane}
        %& 
        %    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}
        Plane
        & 
        \adjustbox{valign=M}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]  {example-image-b}}
        &
            $VVV = \displaystyle \frac{zz}{\displaystyle \int dx}$
    \\   
    \end{tblr}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility with `nicematrix` and `adjustbox`

```
    \documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{nicematrix}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c c c}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=1mm]
    %\Body
    Glissière & 
    \adjustbox{valign=M}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}}
    & $VVV = \displaystyle \frac{zz}{\displaystyle \int dx}$ \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use \adjustbox{valign=m}, adjustbox documentation, section 4.6 Vertical Alignment