# Table with figure inside

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make a table like this but I've been struggling for a few hours.
If you have a link where I can find a sample code, thanks in advance.

[image]

That's what I tried :

```
\usepackage{adjusbox}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.2\textwidth,center=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline \textbf{\underline{Activités}} & \textbf{\underline{Résumé du cours}} & \textbf{\underline{\underline{Évalutation et remarques}}}  \\
\hline \textbf{\underline{Activité}} \\\

    On considère la figure suivante : \\
      \begin{minipage}[c]{3cm}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{sol.jpeg}
     \end{minipage} \\
  
      $\bullet$ La droite $(D)$ présente \\
      
      le sens des rayons issus du soleil $(S)$ \\
      $\bullet$ La droite $(\Delta)$ présente le sol. \\
      1) Représenter sur la droite $(\Delta)$ les \\
      points $A', B'$ et $C'$ les ombres de $A, B$ \\
      et $C$ respectivement. \\
      Qu'elle est l'ombre des segments $[AB]$ et $[BC]$. & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}{l} 
\textbf{\underline{Activité}} \\\

    On considère la figure suivante : \\
      \begin{minipage}[c]{3cm}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{f.jpeg}
     \end{minipage} \\
  
      $\bullet$ La droite $(D)$ présente \\
      
      le sens des rayons issus du soleil $(S)$ \\
      $\bullet$ La droite $(\Delta)$ présente le sol. \\
      1) Représenter sur la droite $(\Delta)$ les \\
      points $A', B'$ et $C'$ les ombres de $A, B$ \\
      et $C$ respectivement. \\
      Qu'elle est l'ombre des segments $[AB]$ \\
      et $[BC]$.
\end{tabular}} \\
\hline \begin{tabular}{c} 
Recommandations \\
pédagogiques
\end{tabular} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}{l} 
$\bullet$ On évitera toute construction théorique de la notion de projection. \\
$\bullet$ On rappellera le théorème de Thalès (sens direct et sens réciproque) puis on introduira à partir d'activités, la \\
propriété de la conservation du coefficient de colinéarité de deux vecteurs par la projection.
\end{tabular}} \\
\hline \begin{tabular}{l} 
Fichiers utilisés dans la \\
préparation du cours
\end{tabular} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}{l} 
$\bullet$ Les orientations pédagogiques. \\
$\bullet$ Livre d'élève. \\
$\bullet$ Des sites électroniques. \\
$\bullet$ Distribution périodique du programme de mathématiques.
\end{tabular}} \\
\hline Rôle de l'enseignant & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}{ll} 
$\bullet$  Ecrire l'activité au tableau \\
$\bullet$  Marquer les difficultés \\
$\bullet$  Répartir les tâches \\
$\bullet$  Donner une durée suffisante pour la recherche individuelle \\
$\bullet$ Diagonaliser les prérequis des apprenants \\
$\bullet$  Noter les observations
\end{tabular}} \\
\hline Rôle de l'apprenant & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}{ll} 
$\bullet$  Ecrire les activités \\
$\bullet$  Répondre aux questions de l'activité avec la justification de ses solutions. \\
$\bullet$  Formuler les résultats de l'activité sous forme d'un théorème, une propriété... \\
$\bullet$ Répondre aux exercices
\end{tabular}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show what you tried. Can you e.g. make a table without the images?

Comment: If you are literally trying to put a `figure` inside a `table`, don't. You can't put a `figure` environment inside a `table`, `tabular` or similar.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315231/how-can-i-put-picture-in-a-table

Comment: Your code does not compile. It lacks a class, a `document` environment, necessary packages ...

Comment: take a look at this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680131/table-vertical-centering-what-am-i-doing-wrong